# Outlook 2010 search doesent work

Tags: windows, email, outlook, windows-update, microsoft-office

I have 50 pc's with office 2010 installed. All machines are running windows 7 x64 and joined to domain. (there is no office 2010 administrative policies defined).Both, windows and office are receiving critical and security updates from on site WSUS server.

The company depends a lot on sending and receiving mails. They receive about 3 000 legit mails per day and also many spam messages.

Suddenly, outlook 2010 search engine stopped working the for every user. It allows entering the term and finds a lot of results, but the result is not relevant to search term. Also, outlook is indexing non-stop so there is never results from week or two. Only older unrelated messages apear in search results.

All .pst are smaller that Microsoft allows for 2010. Email server is on vps server and all accounts are set up as pop3. On mobile phones search engine work well.

What can I do?

Thanks,
Carlo

Comment: try a scanpst run at first please, the tool is hidden in your office folder. it will scan the pst fir any corruption

Comment: I can't run scanpst on all computers because that takes time. Problem must be something else because the problem exist on all computers and different users receive different email messages so I don't belive that pst is corupted. But I can try run on one pc.

Comment: Please try one, my goal is to isolate the trouble, as the pst is a database file, and your symptom look like a corruption.

Comment: So this link fixed it for me:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/4022168/windows-7-sp1-windows-server-2008-r2-sp1-update-kb4022168

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure Windows Search service is up and running
2. Make an index rebuild https://www.wintips.org/fix-outlook-search-problems/